# jQuery check if VARIABLE currentscore is between object keys

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code. I just want to get and display messages after checking if VARIABLE currentscore is between object keys

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class='hidemeadmin'>
    <div data-score="40" data-role="Awww....."></div>
    <div data-score="50" data-role="average"></div>
    <div data-score="60" data-role="good"></div>
    <div data-score="80" data-role="perfect"></div>
</div>
</body>
 <script>

//FUNCTION
$(document).ready(function(){
    var containerScoreText      =   ".hidemeadmin";
    var numberItems             =   $(containerScoreText).children().length;
    var scoreVariable           =   {};// create object
    var currentscore            =   45;
    $(containerScoreText+" div").each(function (i)
    {
        var score               =   $(this).attr("data-score");
        scoreVariable[score]    =   $(this).attr("data-role");
    });
    console.log(scoreVariable);
    //need to check if the currentscore is between 2 object keys 

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: please elaborate this "currentscore is between 2 object keys "

Comment: do you want like for e.g 40-50 will show Aww, 50-60 show average, 60-80 good and >80 perfect or what?

Comment: as you can see I am creating object with key pair, where key is score ... now if value is less than 40 print aww...., if between 40 and 50 print average and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to modify a bit your html so we dont have to parse string to int later on

```
<div class='hidemeadmin'>
    <div data-score=40 data-role="Awww.....">Test</div>
    <div data-score=50 data-role="average">test</div>
    <div data-score=60 data-role="good">test</div>
    <div data-score=80 data-role="perfect">test</div>
</div>
```

Maybe there is a better way, but this works too

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var containerScoreText = ".hidemeadmin";
    var numberItems = $(containerScoreText).children().length;
    var currentscore = 35;
    for (i = 0; i < numberItems; i++) {
        var key1 =$(containerScoreText).children().eq(i).attr("data-score");
        var key2 = $(containerScoreText).children().eq(i+1).attr("data-score");
        if (currentscore >= key1  && key2 >= currentscore) {
            console.log($(containerScoreText).children().eq(i+1).attr("data-role"));
        }

        if(i == 0 && currentscore <= key1){
           console.log($(containerScoreText).children().eq(i).attr("data-role"));
        }

        //in case you want >80 to be perfect...
        if(i == numberItems-1 && currentscore >= key1){
           console.log($(containerScoreText).children().eq(i).attr("data-role"));
        }
     }
});
```

EDIT : here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/67nwsk5j/) link